# How can I force latex to ignore but print #?

Tags: characters

I try to compile a file where many # occur. How can I force LaTeX to print them?

It is especially important (as I import them from a source where I cannot change them), that I can do this in the header of my tex file.

Thanks.

Comment: ``\catcode`\#=12`` to print them, ``\catcode`\#=9`` to ignore them.  But don't actually do this!

Comment: Are you typesetting source code or something? In that case, you might be interested in the `listings` or `minted` package.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!!  A better solution might be to put in imported code inside a `verbatim` environment. it is difficult to answer you question, however, without more information. Please add a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). Currently we have to guess what packages etc you are using and this makes it really hard to help you. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: Thank you, but the imported "text" is a very long tabular and is therefore in longtab.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*After* `\begin{document}` (so after the `aux` file and any packages have been input) then  you could do

```
\catcode`\#=12
```

to make `#` a normal character.

You probably should have

```
\catcode`\#=6
```

just before `\end{document}` to put things back.

If at any point you include a file that makes definitions you will probably need to set the catcode back to 6 while the file is being read.

Comment: Catcodechanges are local, so if one puts the

    \catcode`\#=12

sequence into a group `\#` would return to its normal catcode, hence, meaning afterwards.

Comment: @Moss_the_TeXie yes but but putting the entire document into a group may have other effects (not least on memory usage) without an example from the OP, this way seemed safer.

Comment: Sorry, that work's perfectly fine. Thanks a lot!